# Possible to dry-run a `git revert`?

Tags: git, git-revert

I need to revert a commit but only if there will not be conflicts. Something like `git revert --only-if-no-conflicts` but there isn't such option and there is no `--dry-run` (`--no-commit` will still affect working copy which I need to avoid).

In this case, the revert is run from a script so I cannot manually inspect whether there have been conflicts or not. I can do that somehow from the script but before diving into that, isn't there some clever way to make Git do the revert only if it will succeed without conflicts?

Answer (score 4):

The script should:

**Branch, revert, observe.**

If you don't want to touch your working tree, you can create a new directory with **`git-new-workdir`**, for example in **`/tmp`**.

Then you could plainly,

```
new branch $ git revert --no-edit ce6982e || \
                 { export REVERT_FAILED=yes; git revert --abort; }
```

**Go back to the original branch and act on the observation, ie revert if the revert on the staging branch was successful.**

Comment: Branch + revert will still affect the working copy which I need to avoid. (Making a copy / clone and trying it there is also not an option, I am quite constrained by the fact that the "dry run" needs to happen on the one and only working copy.)

Comment: I want to affect the file system but only if the revert succeeds without conflicts. In other words, I somehow need to find out if it will succeed before actually executing it.

Comment: @Borek That's impossible, in the case of revert git needs to apply the diff, and only then you'll know if there are conflicts. That application has to happen *somewhere*, so if you don't want to affect your working tree, do it in */tmp* as suggested above.

Comment: Git probably knows whether there are conflicts or not before writing the markers to files but ok, it's possible that it doesn't expose this information in any way so as things stand, the working copy updates are unavoidable. I'll try `git-new-workdir`, thanks. (Will leave this question open a bit longer to see if anyone comes up with some different solution.)

Answer (score 1):

`git revert` will add a new commit on top. So you can do `git reset --soft HEAD~1` to undo the latest commit.

BUT: *source 2* about *revert* says:

> These commands *(cherry-pick and revert)* construct a new commit that does not preserve any parent information pointing back to the old one. Use with care.

I'm not a git master (and I'm not sure about the relevance of this warning). I triple-checked it with these sources

- about git revert [source 1](https://ohshitgit.com/#undo-a-commit) and [source 2, p.51](https://web.mit.edu/nelhage/Public/git-slides-2009.pdf)
- about git reset [source 1](https://sillevl.gitbooks.io/git/content/advanced/reset-checkout-revert/) and [source 2](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-last-commit/)